# Need help/advice on how to fill in a groove/trench on a model's surface

Tags: edit-mode

I am working on a personal project and am trying to remove a trench (not sure if proper term but describes it accurately) that runs along the model.

[image]

Is there any way to easily fill this in to be inline with the rest of the model? If there isn't an easy way, but you have an idea of how to do it, please post it. Thanks.

Comment: you should show the topology of your mesh, or share your file. Have you tried to select the opposite edges then ctrl F > Grid Fill and play with the parameters on the bottom of the T menu?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it to my standards. I selected a loop of vertices around and above the trench, hid it and removed the trench. Then I un-hid the loop and made some edges that ran across the new gap. Filled in the holes with faces made from the new edges and the loop.

Not the best or most elegant solution, but I wanted to get it done ASAP. Please let me know if anyone has a better way of doing it.